# Calculate time diffrence in SQL with shifts

Tags: sql, oracle

i have two table 
the first table contains the record of a ticket with start date and end date

```
 start_date           | End_Date
 21-02-2017 07:52:32  | 22-02-2017 09:56:32
 21-02-2017 09:52:32  | 23-02-2017 17:52:32
```

the second table contains the details of the weekly shift:

```
 shift_day | Start_Time | End_Time
  MON        9:00          18:00
  TUE        10:00         19:00
  WED        9:00          18:00
  THU        10:00         19:00
  FRI        9:00          18:00
```

I am looking to get the time difference in the first table which will only include the time as per the second table.

Comment: What do you expect as an answer and what is the logic to get to that answer?

Comment: yes want kind of logic can i use here to obtain it @MT0

Comment: No, you need to tell us what are you trying to do and if you do not know what answer to expect how will we ever know? We cannot guess your requirements so you need to help us by telling us (in words) what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i have a table in which the incidents are tracked. The first table contains the from time and to time taken by the incident . i am looking to calculate the time taken by the incidents which falls in the time frame described in the second able. i would like to avoid calculating time for the instance while the clock is out of the timing described in the second table. @mt0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a recursive sub-query factoring clause to generate each day within your time ranges and then correlate that with your shifts to restrict the time for each day to be within the shift hours and then aggregate to get the total:

**Oracle 18 Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE times ( start_date, End_Date ) AS
SELECT DATE '2017-02-21' + INTERVAL '07:52:32' HOUR TO SECOND,
       DATE '2017-02-22' + INTERVAL '09:56:32' HOUR TO SECOND
FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-02-21' + INTERVAL '09:52:32' HOUR TO SECOND,
       DATE '2017-02-23' + INTERVAL '17:52:32' HOUR TO SECOND
FROM   DUAL;

CREATE TABLE weekly_shifts ( shift_day, Start_Time, End_Time ) AS
SELECT 'MON', INTERVAL '09:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, INTERVAL '18:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'TUE', INTERVAL '10:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, INTERVAL '19:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'WED', INTERVAL '09:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, INTERVAL '18:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'THU', INTERVAL '10:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, INTERVAL '19:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'FRI', INTERVAL '09:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, INTERVAL '18:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH days ( id, start_date, day_start, day_end, end_date ) AS (
  SELECT ROWNUM,
         start_date,
         start_date,
         LEAST( TRUNC( start_date ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY, end_date ),
         end_date
  FROM   times
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         start_date,
         day_end,
         LEAST( day_end + INTERVAL '1' DAY, end_date ),
         end_date
  FROM   days
  WHERE  day_end < end_date
)
SELECT start_date,
       end_date,
       SUM( shift_end - shift_start ) AS days_worked_on_shift
FROM   (
  SELECT ID,
         start_date,
         end_date,
         GREATEST( day_start, TRUNC( day_start ) + start_time ) AS shift_start,
         LEAST( day_end, TRUNC( day_start ) + end_time ) AS shift_end
  FROM   days d
         INNER JOIN
         weekly_shifts w
         ON ( TO_CHAR( d.day_start, 'DY' ) = w.shift_day )
)
GROUP BY id, start_date, end_date;
```

**Result**:

```
START_DATE          END_DATE            DAYS_WORKED_ON_SHIFT
------------------- ------------------- --------------------
2017-02-21 07:52:32 2017-02-22 09:56:32 0.414259259259259259
2017-02-21 09:52:32 2017-02-23 17:52:32 1.078148148148148148
```

Comment: I have small change to the requirement. I have a set of dates that also need to excluded. can i put the table in the as a query in the recursive part and run it. @MT0

Comment: @SrinivasPusapati Probably not in the recursive part but in the inner query at the bottom. But comments is not the place to answer that question - better to try it and if you get a problem then ask a new question with your attempt included.